# How install "Laravelium Sitemap package " in laravel-6.20

Tags: laravel

My laravel version is 6.20

I want to install "Laravelium Sitemap package " but not install and I face to this error :

Problem 1
- The requested package laravel/socialite (locked at v5.1.2, required as ^5.2) is satisfiable by laravel/socialite[v5.1.2] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

Comment: I use following comment

"   composer require laravelium/sitemap:'6.0.*'   "

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Composer: how can I install another dependency without updating old ones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15212381/composer-how-can-i-install-another-dependency-without-updating-old-ones)

Answer (score 1):

It says it needs laravel/socialite version 5.2 or newer and it can't update.
You can edit the composer.json and change the version from `"laravel/socialite": "^5.1.2"` to `"laravel/socialite": "^5.2"`.
Be aware, maybe you have other packages that depend on socialite 5.1.2.